# vba that search for a value if it matches find closest date

Tags: vba, date, find

i wrote a code for a workbook that have two worksheet´s, in the ProximoPedido (sheet) in column "A" there is a range of a values (integer number) and in colunm "B" there is a date associated, and in the ChekingList (sheet) there is the colunm "A" with the values (wich must match with "A" of ProximoPedido) and colunm "E" with dates. If value of cell A of CheckingList matches with value of "A" of ProximoPedido then  search in "E" of ChekingList for next ( or closest higher) date of "B" from ProximoPedido.

Sheet: CheckingList

A-----------------------------------------E

1----------------------------------2009-10-30 12:00

3 ---------------------------------2009-10-29  13:00

2---------------------------------2009-10-29  12:20

50--------------------------------2009-10-19  10:20

24--------------------------------2009-10-28  10:20

3----------------------------------2009-10-28  10:20  <-------- ( MATCH!)

Sheet: Proximo Pedido

A----------------------------------------B

4----------------------------------2009-10-28  10:20

20---------------------------------2009-10-29  13:00

3----------------------------------2009-10-19  15:20

24---------------------------------2009-10-29  13:40

3-----------------------------------2009-10-27  13:20 <------------ (example)

i wrote a formula first with conditioning VLOOKUP and other with INDEX MATCH, but the VLOOKUP gave me the last value of all dates in CheckingList, and then i tried this code :
Sub TempoTotal1()

```
    Dim CheckingList As Worksheet
    Dim ProximPedido As Worksheet
    Dim tear1 As Range
    Dim inicio As Range
    Dim tear2 As Range
    Dim saida As Range
    Dim diferença As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim i As Integer





Set tear1 = Worksheets("CheckingList").Range("a2").CurrentRegion
Set inicio = Worksheets("CheckingList").Range("e2").CurrentRegion
Set tear2 = Worksheets("ProximoPedido").Range("a1").CurrentRegion
Set saida = Worksheets("ProximoPedido").Range("b2").CurrentRegion
Set diferença = Worksheets("ProximoPedido").Range("c2").CurrentRegion



On Error Resume Next

For Each cell1 In tear1
If tear1.Cells.Value = tear2.Cells.Value Then

For Each cell2 In inicio


If tear2.Cells.Value > saida.Cells.Value Then
diferença.Cells.Value = inicio.Cells.Value - saida.Cells.Value

End If
Exit For
Next cell2


End If
Exit For
Next cell1








End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setup 2 variables in your code

1. The first will track a cell location `DIM MatchCell as Range`
2. The second will track the delta between the source cell and the
   Match Cell `Dim Targetdelta as Double`

Now, loop through the data on Sheet: Proximo Pedido performing the following logical steps

1. Calculate the absolute delta between the date on the current cell and and the date in the CheckList
2. IF that delta is less than the current value of Targetdelta
3. THEN Update delta to the new value and record the current address in the MatchCell variable
4. Continue Looping
5. After the loop, you know which cell was closest - its stored in the MatchCell variable